# Make Bootstrap 3.0 input-groups display inline

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently struggeling making from elements if twitter bootsrap 3.0 display in one without breaks in it. What happens when I make a wrapper float is that the input elements cut off.

[Look at this jsfiddle please](http://jsfiddle.net/BTAaU/9/)

```
    <form id="commentform" method="post" action="http://devsite.localhost/wp-comments-post.php" name="commentform">
   <span class="comment-form-author"><label class="obscure" for="author">Name</label><span class="input-group span2"><input type="text" placeholder="Name *" aria-required="true" tabindex="1" size="30" value="" name="author" id="author" /></span></span> <span class="comment-form-email"><label class="obscure" for="author">Email</label><span class="input-group span3"><input type="text" placeholder="Email *" aria-required="true" tabindex="2" size="30" value="" name="email" id="email" /></span></span> <span class="comment-form-url"><label class="obscure" for="url">Website</label><span class="input-group span3"><input type="text" placeholder="Website" tabindex="3" size="30" value="" name="url" class="input-medium" id="url" /></span></span>
   <div class="comment-form-comment">
      <textarea placeholder="Comment" aria-required="true" tabindex="4" rows="8" cols="45" name="comment" id="comment">
      </textarea>
   </div>
   <!-- #form-section-comment .form-section -->
   <p class="form-submit"><input type="submit" value="Post Comment" id="submit" name="submit" /> <input type="hidden" id="comment_post_ID" value="14" name="comment_post_ID" /> <input type="hidden" value="0" id="comment_parent" name="comment_parent" /></p>
</form>
```

css

```
@import url('http://my-hardware.net/bs/bootstrap.css');

/* hiding content but not from screen readers, used in comments form */
.obscure {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.comment-form-email{
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

For showing purposes I just added my attempt to one of the 3 imputs I want to line up.

Does anyone has a idea how to make this work?

Comment: I think maybe it is a problem with the bootstrap 3.0 (the glyphicons are uneven), in the [official site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) it still the version 2.2.2 and using it works just fine, like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BTAaU/10/)

Comment: @Lucas Lazaro You don't get it at all! I want the input fields side by side **in the same line**. Things have changed in 3.0 yes but there is no problem at all i dont want to recreate the example man! I want to display them after each other! I git this with 2.2.2 and you **dont** in your example. Read and look at the css next time! And the glyph-icons are not shows just bc they are simply not there (in path)

Comment: Using JSFiddle's tidy seems to reveal some HTML issues. I'd start by validating your code.

Answer (score 6):

I think this should work...

```
<div class="controls-row">
    <div class="control-group col col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">X</span>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group col col-lg-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Y</span>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```